# Add a row to UITableView without using reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata, nsindexpath

I have a ViewController that creates a new object and then back in the FirstViewController.m I have an unwind method that should update the tableView with a row for the new object. Using the reloadData method won't work because it reloads all of the cells which affects the methods I have in those cells. I would like to just add a new cell without reloading the entire tableView. My unwind method looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)unwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    ABCAddItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    ABCItem *item = source.object;

    if (item != nil) {
        [self.objectArray addObject:item];

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

I've tried adding these lines instead of [self.tableView reloadData]:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.objectArray indexOfObject:item] inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

However, the app crashes and I get this message:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

The number of rows in the tableView is determined by `[self.objectArray count]` in `the numberOfRowsInSection:` method.

How can I make this work? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You have to update your data source (`self.objectArray`) with the additional data just before calling `insertRowsAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I tried to just replace the `[self.tableView reloadData]` line but that produces the error I mentioned. I add the object to the array right before then.

Comment: A call to `reloadData` will not give the error you posted. That would only be from the call to `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:`. BTW - you need to insert the row in the same location you add it to your array.

Comment: I can't use `reloadData` because reloading the entire table restarts some of the methods

Answer (score 0):

Error is saying your interface update expected 2 rows to display, but your data source only contains 1 row after update.

Is your "item" object an `[NSNull null]` value?

The line `if(item != nil)` can equate to true if item is an `[NSNull null]` value.

Could you try putting this extra check

```
if(item != nil && item != [NSNull null])
{
    ...
}
```

Or use a breakpoint and debugger to print out the value of item:

```
lldb> po item
```